# Why there is no difference between a grounded and an insulated sphere? (Classical Electrodynamics - Jackson)

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, conductors

There is a statement in [Classical Electrodynamics Third Edition](https://www.wiley.com/en-us/Classical+Electrodynamics%2C+3rd+Edition-p-9780471309321#description-section) 2.5 section that I cannot understand.

The book uses the image charge method to solve the induced charge density problem on a conducting sphere as the picture below.

[image]

At the end of the section, there is a statement mentioning,

> We note that the surface integral of this charge density vanishes, so that there is no difference between a grounded and an insulated sphere.

[image]

Here is my question. **Why there is no difference between a grounded and an insulated sphere?**

Comment: Grounded simply means that you are imposing the potential of the conductor and insulated means you are imposing the charge of a conductor (since there are no charge flux). Jackson solve the problem by assuming the sphere to be grounded (only one image charge each). Since the the sphere is initially neutral and at the end is again neutral (integral of surface charge vanishes), it is as if the sphere was insulated as well.

Comment: Why only one image charge each means that the sphere is assumed grounded?

Comment: If the sphere is insulated, you’ll need an extra virtual charge at the center to compensate the induced opposite charge.